# Convert JSON to List<List<String>> in Java

Tags: java, json, string, arraylist, gson

I am having Json String this way,

```
json= [{"id":"1","label":"2","code":"3"},{"id":"4","label":"5","code":"6"}]
```

I tried converting it into Java Object this way, by using Gson,

and a Pojo called Item.java with fields namely id,label and code and getter setters for them.

```
String id;
    String label;
    String code;
    //getter setters

Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Item> items = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Item>>(){}.getType());
```

Then converted Java Object to List  this way,

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Object object : items) {
            strings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
}
```

My output is this way,

```
[Item [id=1, label=2, code=3], Item [id=6, label=5, code=6]
```

But i need it as `List<List<String>>` and without [Items] i.e,

```
[[id=1, label=2, code=3],[id=4, label=5, code=6]]

or direct 



List<List<String>>
```

without key.

```
[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
```

What is that I am missing? Can some body help me in this?

Comment: Do you actually need a `List<List<String>>`, or is it just that you don't like the way `Item#toString()` formats the data?

Comment: I'm really not seeing a list of lists here.  I don't think you need one, personally.  What does the `toString` method of `Item` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you already have posted gives you a `List<Item>`, so it sounds like you're just unsure how to build a `List<List<String>>` out of it.

What you're doing here:

```
for (Object object : items) {
```

is failing to take advantage of the fact that `items` is a `List<Item>`, not a `List<Object>`.

You can create an enhanced for-loop that pulls actual `Item`s out like so:

```
for (Item item : items) {
```

This will let you properly access the data in them to build a sub-list:

```
    String json = "[{id:1,label:2,code:3},{id:4,label:5,code:6}]";
    List<Item> items = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Item>>(){}.getType());

    List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Item item : items) {
        List<String> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        subList.add(item.getId());
        subList.add(item.getLabel());
        subList.add(item.getCode());
        listOfLists.add(subList);
    }

    System.out.println(listOfLists);  // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

**However**

If it's just that you don't like the output format of a `List<Item>`, a much simpler way to fix your code is to just override `toString()` in such a way that it prints what you need.

If I create the `toString()` method in `Item` to look like this:

```
public class Item {
    private String id;
    private String label;
    private String code;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + id + ", " + label + ", " + code + "]";
    }

    // getters, setters...
}
```

...then when I print a `List<Item>` it looks the way you want it:

```
    String json = "[{id:1,label:2,code:3},{id:4,label:5,code:6}]";
    List<Item> items = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Item>>(){}.getType());
    System.out.println(items);  // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```